# Promise exception handling and try/catch doing the opposite of what I would expect

Tags: typescript, promise

Suppose I have the following functions

```ts
async function test() {
  return new Promise<string>((reject, resolve) => {
    resolve("test OK");
  });
}

async function test2() {
  return new Promise<string>((reject, resolve) => {
    reject("test error");
  });
}

async function f() {
  try {
    await test();
  } catch (err) {
    console.log("error test 1");
  }
}

async function f2() {
  try {
    await test2();
  } catch (err) {
    console.log("error test 2");
  }
}

f(); //This prints 'error test 1'
f2(); //This prints nothing
```

My assumption (obviously incorrect) is that calling `resolve` in the promise returned by `test()` would result in `f()` executing without issue, and conversely, calling `reject` in `test2()` would result in the catch block of `f2()` executing. However, the opposite happens. What is my fundamental misunderstanding as to why calling `resolve()` results in an error being caught?

Comment: There is absolutely no reason to pass an async function into the `Promise` constructor

Comment: i've removed the async modifiers - they don't do anything for this example. but understood.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that `resolve` and `reject` should be reversed. The arguments to the Promise constructor depend on position rather than name, so the names don't mean what you expect. The first argument will always resolve, the second will always reject.

```js
return new Promise<string>((resolve, reject) => {
```

Promise constructor MDN docs for reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/Promise#creating_a_new_promise

Comment: i'm so embarrassed. I've been staring at this problem for so long. thank you so much.

Comment: Don't be embarrassed, we've all stared at code a little too long :)